# Job on Upstart not started

Tags: bash, scripts, upstart, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to start my application at boot, but I can not ... the script in upstart calls another script, I'm not getting or whether the 2nd script is called, follows the two scripts:
**1º Script**

```
description "Start OpenProject"
start on startup
script
exec su openproject -c "/home/openproject/Scripts/start-openproject.sh"
end script
```

**2º Script**

```
#!/bin/bash -x

rm -f ~/server.log

source ~/.nodeenv/bin/activate >> ~/server.log 2>&1
cd /home/openproject/openproject
bundle exec rails server >> ~/server.log 2>&1
```

The file server.log it is not being created. Someone help me?

Comment: You may want to replace `~/` by the actual `/home/username/` path. Just in case the script gets executed as the root user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had tried before, but it does not. Note that in 1 script, I use the -c so that the command is run with the user openproject